# How can I call a PHP function stored as a string from within another PHP function?

Tags: php

I find myself in the situation where I need to call a PHP function stored as a string from another PHP function.

```
<?php
$phpcodestring = "<?php echo 'Hello World!' ?>";
echo $phpcodestring;
?>
```

How can I get Hello World to render to screen with the above structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back up a few steps - why do you need to do that?

99.9% of the time there is a better way than `eval()`.

Or you could use `create_function()` which internally uses something like `eval()` so isn't much better, especially when you are not defining the function body directly with a string literal so you can be sure there and then there is nothing potentially dangerous.

Comment: I have PHP piece of code that exists in a WordPress theme options panel setting. I need to get this code into the interpreter and make it run.

Comment: @trnsrmr Ah WordPress, I should have known! Just hope there are no SQL injection holes.

Comment: I'd rather not doing anything that makes my theme more un secure. Will try and figure out a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the infamous `eval()` if you thoroughly trust the source of the string. How the hell did you find yourself in that situation?

Comment: The PHP code I'm trying to run is stored as a string in a WordPress theme options panel.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case of eval().

```
eval("echo 'Hello world!';");
```

You should always consider whether it's a good idea or not, though. Security considerations of eval() can be daunting.

G

Comment: I'd rather not create any security issues.

Comment: You just need to handle the inputs to eval carefully. It really, really is a last resort type of approach, though. 

Perhaps save the options panel setting as a file and include it?

Comment: Hmmm, will try and think of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the eval() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Answer (score 0):

eval($phpcodestring);

Comment: This did not work. Here is my code:

    <?php
    $phpcodestring = "<?php echo 'Hello World!' ?>";
    echo eval($phpcodestring);
    ?>

Here is the error:

    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /Users/jc/Sites/test.php(3) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: you musst strip the <?php and ?> in the code string and attach a semicolon at the end of the string like 
$phpcodestring = "echo 'Hello World!';";

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use [create_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) method, which is a poor implementation of lambda-style functions in PHP.

Comment: Doesn't create_function have the same security flaws as eval?

Comment: @trnsfrmr it is, but the solution is a bit more 'elegant' IMO